# What i miss here? Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Anyone know what i miss as i found a bug if i put 2 uppercase letters after an apostrophe or a hyphen.

Write a regular expression as a string (including the quotation marks) that matches the pattern of a last name, as follows:

- must be between 1 and 32 characters total
- must contain only letters and possibly an apostrophe and possibly a hyphen
- must start with an uppercase letter
- must contain all lowercase letters after the first letter except: the letter following an apostrophe or hyphen must be uppercase
- the name must not end with an apostrophe or hyphen

My code:

```py
string = "Mc'Tiray_JJay"

if re.findall("^[A-Z][a-zA-Z'`-`]{0,31}", string):
    if re.findall("[\'-][A-Z][a-z]", string):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

The result is yes even i have 2 JJ

Result should be:

```
string = "Mc'Tiray-JJay" => no
string = "Mc'Tiray-Jay" => yes
```

Comment: Zero or one apostrophe?  Zero or one hyphens? I understand an apostrophe cannot be followed by a hyphen, and vice-versa. Correct?

Comment: Did you know hyphen is written as `-` and underscore as `_`? So your second string shouldn't match too! as it has `_`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, it's correct

Comment: @gajendragarg sorry i mean a hyphen -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the string by attempting to match the following regular expression:

```
^(?!.*(['-]).*\1)(?!.*['-](?:[a-z'-]|$))(?!.*(?<=[^'-])[A-Z])[A-Z][A-Za-z'-]{0,31}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eu7LzU/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                # match beginning of string
```

```
(?!              # begin negative lookahead to require at most 1
                 # apostrophe or hyphen
  .*             # match >= 0 characters
  (['-])         # match in char in char class and save to capture group 1
  .*             # match >= 0 characters
  \1             # match the content of capture group 1
)                # end negative lookahead
```

```
(?!              # begin negative lookahead to require an apostrophe or 
                 # hyphen to be followed by an uppercase letter
  .*             # match >= 0 characters
  ['-]           # match in char in char class
  (?:            # begin non-capture group
    [a-z'-]      # match a char in char class
    |            # or
    $            # match end of string 
  )              # end non-capture group
)                # end negative lookahead
```

```
(?!              # begin negative lookahead to prevent an uppercase letter
                 # from being preceded by a char other than an apostrophe
                 # or hyphen 
  .*             # match >= 0 characters
  (?<=           # begin positive lookbehind
    [^'-]        # match a char in char class
  )              # end positive lookbehind
  [A-Z]          # match a char in char class
)                # end negative lookahead
```

```
[A-Z]            # match a char in char class
[A-Za-z'-]{0,31} # match 0-31 chars in char class
$                # match end of string
```

Comment: For a string of length more than 32, pattern match will be True. Probably, need a boundary or `$` :)

Comment: @gajendragarg, thanks for the heads-up. I fixed that and also removed a redundant lookahead. I would appreciate a close look. For long expressions like this one it's easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Agreed. It's a long regex. Pattern works very well :)

Comment: 100k!! Congrats :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Congrats for your 100k! Those are well deserved.

Comment: Thanks, @Eric. I see you've also hit a milestone recently.

Comment: I'm happy about 50k, but those mostly come from residual upvotes. I haven't been very active after my ruby and python golden badges. You seem to have been continually busy. Thanks for your contribution to the ruby world!